# Seeking terse idiom

Tags: idiom-requests

There is a concept in computing that involves training AI with large volumes of data to produce biases that, while not strictly correct, produce very good outcomes. Large language models and other AI illustrate the results of such practices.

If a human being were to train themselves similarly, by acquiring biases that lead to very good outcomes by exposure to vast amounts of experience, it would produce something like "wisdom". Such a person might reasonably be described as "experienced".

The question is, is there a generic term that can be used to describe such a person or class of people?

The term "cultured intelligence" came to mind, but that term may not be widely understood at first glance by English speakers. **Is there some construction that will evoke the idea of being trained on large amounts of data without any preexisting rules having been learned, and training that may result in very good outcomes without producing correspondingly good internal models of reality?**

Note: experience and wisdom already have much common usage baggage and are undesirable in this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no term that will answer exactly  to the characteristics you have in mind. There is a well known term though that comes close : it is "*educated guessing*".

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/educated-guess))  An educated guess is a guess which is based on a certain amount of knowledge and is therefore likely to be correct.
> • Estimating the right cooking time will always be an educated guess.

> ([educated guessing](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/GMAT_Roadmap_Expert_Advice_Through_Test/0fQPDQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22educated+guessing%22&pg=PA115&printsec=frontcover))

"Educated guessing" is also called "educated selection".

Comment: Yeah if there was one i would probably already know it. What I'd like is for someone to coin a term that works. I cannot, thus far.

Comment: @fertilizerspike The "limit term" does exist, but it is not what you are seeking, of course; I'm thinking of "innate knowledge" (but it is knowledge prior to all experience).

Comment: @fertilizerspike You want someone to *coin* an idiom? That's not how idioms work.

Comment: @Robusto I believe that most people on this site [consider such requests to be off-topic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8077/can-a-newly-constructed-word-answer-a-single-word-request/8079#8079), too.